# crear usuarios en openldap desde un SCV

Tags: mysql, python, ubuntu, script, openldap

Buenas a todos! estoy comenzando en el mundo de ubuntu y también de Ldap y tengo un inconveniente ya que quiero hacer un script que me permita crear usuarios mediante un archivo SCV el cual tiene tres campos (nombre, apellido y correo). 
Una vez que el usuario sea cargado en el ldap despues tengo que migrar toda la información en un archivo Mysql.
En si lo que pido es que alguien me ayude a ver si el script está mal o cual puede ser el problema de que no se estén creando los usuarios cuando lo ejecuto. Por ultimo también les solicito ayuda para que me expliquen como hago la exportación a un archivo mysql

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-
#enconding: utf-8
# -*- coding: 850 -*-
import smtplib
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist
import getpass
import csv, operator
import urllib2 


from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTP 

#Solicitamos la password del admin de LDAP
password = getpass.getpass('Por favor ingrese su clave: ')

#Realizamos la conexion al servidor de ldap
uri = ldap.initialize("ldap://10.0.2.15:389")
uri.simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com",password)
uidNumber = 2010
gidNumber = 2001

#genero la nuevas contraseñas formatoRabdom
from random import SystemRandom
longitud = 18
valores = 
u"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
<=>@#%&+"
cryptogen = SystemRandom()
contrasena = ""
while longitud > 0:
    contrasena = contrasena + cryptogen.choice(valores)
    longitud = longitud - 1

#abro el archivo usuario y almaceno los datos en dos variables para 
#crear el usuario y enviar el correo
csvarchivo = open('/home/luis/ml/usuarios.csv')
entrada = csv.reader(csvarchivo)
for i in entrada:   
usuario = i[0]+i[1]
correo = i[2]

      #cargo al usuario en LDAP

dn= ("uid=%s,ou=people,dc=ldap,dc=com" %usuario)
attrs = {}
attrs['objectclass'] = 
['top','posixAccount','inetOrgPerson','ldapPublicKey']
attrs['cn'] = str(i[0])
attrs['uid'] = str(usuario)
attrs['sn'] = str(i[1]).encode('ascii','ignore')
attrs['uidNumber'] = str(uidNumber)
attrs['gidNUmber'] = str(gidNumber)
attrs['mail'] = str(i[2]).encode('ascii','ignore')
attrs['sshPublicKey'] = "ssh-rsa" + str(contrasena)
attrs['homeDirectory'] = ['/home/%s' % (str(usuario))]
attrs['loginShell'] = ['/bin/bash']
ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)
attrs ['ShadowLastChange'] = 0
uri.add(dn,ldif)
uidNumber = uidNumber + 1
uri.unbind_s()

#Envio un correo con los datos al nuevo usuario
from_address = 
str('correodepruebasldap@gmail.com').encode('ascii','ignore')
passwr = 'correodeprueba234'
to_address = str(i[2]).encode('utf-8')
message = "Tu nuevo usuario es: " + usuario + '\n\n' + u"Tu contrasena 
: " + contrasena + '\n\n' + "Por favor ingresar haga click en el 
siguiente link: "
mime_message = MIMEText(message, "plain")
mime_message["From"] = from_address
mime_message["To"] = to_address
mime_message["Subject"] = "Nuevo registro de usuario"
smtp = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(from_address,passwr)
smtp.sendmail(from_address, to_address, mime_message.as_string())
smtp.quit()
csvarchivo.close()
```

Comment: Te recomiendo mejorar la forma de pegar el código en SO, por ejemplo `crear el usuario y enviar el correo` es una instrucción que no es correcta para python, por lo que no se si es un error tipografico o un error en el pegado del texto.

Comment: Disculpá ahí edito, es mi primer post